# How to handle errors in knex

Tags: error-handling, knex.js

I am using knex.js in my node project to handle sql database. I am trying to handle the query errors but it is throwing the entire query in my error.

I printed the errors and found out that it returns code in the error I just want to use that as a point and display my own error message, my question here is that if there is a list of the error codes so that I can make use of it?

I read knex.js documentation but I don't seem to find anything regarding it.

Comment: Knex queries returns a regular `Promise`, you can use `catch` or try & catch with combination of async & await

Comment: The errors knex throw are usually directly those errors which are thrown by the database driver / from the database. So the list you are looking for depends on the database that you are using.

Comment: I am using mariadb/mysql and I used try catch to handle the errors.